# png из SQLite на Android

Tags: android, delphi, png, delphi-xe7

пишу приложение под Android (среда разработки Delphi XE7)
имеется база данных SQLite, в одной из таблиц есть Blob поле, где находятся png-файлы
вот такой простой код по извлечению значения из Blob и отрисовки на TImage

```pascal
BlobStream := FDTable.CreateBlobStream(FDTable.FieldByName('FramePng'), TBlobStreamMode.bmRead);
bmp := TBitmap.CreateFromStream(BlobStream);
ImagePage.Bitmap.Canvas.DrawBitmap(bmp, RectF(0, 0, bmp.Width - 1, bmp.Height - 1), r, 1);
bmp.Free;
BlobStream.Free;
```

при запуске приложения под Windows - все работает четко, а под Android получаю ошибку

> Project Project1.apk raised exception class EBitmapLoadingFailed with
> message 'Loading bitmap failed.'.

в строке

```pascal
bmp := TBitmap.CreateFromStream(BlobStream);
```

пробовал в базу загонять и jpg и bmp - ошибка одинакова
подскажите как правильно преобразовать Blob TBitmap под Android

---

нашел решение, но не очень красивое
под Android получилось только через сохранение файла на "диск"
может подскажите более лучшее решение?

```pascal
var
{$IFDEF MSWINDOWS}
BlobStream: TStream;
{$ENDIF}
{$IFDEF ANDROID}
BlobStream: TMemoryStream;
fn: string;
{$ENDIF}
bmp: TBitmap;
r: TRectF;

.................

{$IFDEF MSWINDOWS}
BlobStream := FDTable.CreateBlobStream(FDTable.FieldByName('FramePng'), TBlobStreamMode.bmRead);
bmp := TBitmap.CreateFromStream(BlobStream);
{$ENDIF}
{$IFDEF ANDROID}
fn := TPath.Combine(TPath.GetDocumentsPath, '1.png');
BlobStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
TBlobField(FDTable.FieldByName('FramePng')).SaveToStream(BlobStream);
BlobStream.Position := 0;
BlobStream.SaveToFile(fn);
bmp := TBitmap.CreateFromFile(fn);
TFile.Delete(fn);
{$ENDIF}
ImagePage.Bitmap.Canvas.DrawBitmap(bmp, RectF(0, 0, bmp.Width - 1, bmp.Height - 1), r, 1);
bmp.Free;
BlobStream.Free;
```

Comment: Хранить Бинарные данные в БД плохо и то что вы назвали не красивым решением - самое верное. Хранить изображения лучше на диске, а в базе можно запоминать ее название или путь на ваш выбор.

Comment: хранение изображений (их много) с файлах баз (их тоже много), обусловлено структурой проекта

Comment: сложно представить структуру проекта где это нельзя сделать иначе, кроме одного - когда подобную структуру сделали до вас.

Answer (score 1):

Пожалуй, лучшим решением в вашем случае было бы хранение самих изображений в папке /assets, а в базе данных - хранение только путей к этим изображениям. Когда у вас "в руках" оказывается путь к нужному вам изображению, вы просто извлекаете его из ассетов следующих образом:

```
Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(getAssets().open("dir_name/pic_name.png"), null);
```

Теперь делайте со своим Drawable что пожалете. Хранить изображения в базе данных категорически не рекомендую.

Answer (score -1):

Возможно вам поможет скомбинировать оба варианта и сделать копирование в битмап через промежуточный стрим:

```
BlobStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
TBlobField(FDTable.FieldByName('FramePng')).SaveToStream(BlobStream);
BlobStream.Position := 0;
bmp := TBitmap.CreateFromStream(BlobStream);
ImagePage.Bitmap.Canvas.DrawBitmap(bmp, RectF(0, 0, bmp.Width - 1, bmp.Height - 1), r, 1);
bmp.Free;
BlobStream.Free;
```

Comment: конечно пробовал - ошибка та же

Comment: "минус" за решение без объяснения. (с)

Comment: @null наконец-то у меня есть личный минусатор (см. предыдущий ответ null) :-)